# Hot Network Questions disappear when searching in page using CTRL + F

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Steps to reproduce:

Go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933080/same-type-of-codes-but-one-code-shows-exception), press <kbd>crtl + f</kbd>, search for "MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException" and hit enter twice. The second match will be in the right panel where the hot questions disappear (The whole right panel disappeared for me, including the "Related" panel)

I tried that on two machines, on both Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Can someone validate this please?

[image]

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 35.0.1916.17 dev-m, Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: Add Firefox and Safari on the browsers list and machine++ too :)

Comment: Producing on chrome only for me.

Comment: No repro (Firefox 28 on Windows 7 x64).

Comment: Reproduced; the linked question on the right is wider than the space in the sidebar, and the highlight 'scrolls' the sidebar div to reveal the part of the link that matches the text.

Comment: In other words, the whole sidebar is 'hidden' because a previously hidden overflow on the right has been moved into view. You could re-reveal the hot questions list by searching for 'hot network questions', for example.

Comment: We need to hit enter thrice now, because the OP of that post edited it.

Comment: This appears to be a [bug on Chrome itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093148/chrome-search-feature-ctrlf-finds-hidden-text-but-its-invisible)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That's a different issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the linked question in the sidebar. It's full title is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

The long exception name doesn't fit in the sidebar, and is not wrapped. Only the first part (up to the `j` of `jdbc4`  is still fully visible. When your browser highlights matches, the sidebar div content is 'scrolled' to the left to reveal the hidden part of the link title that  matches.

However, this means that the rest of the properly wrapped sidebar contents have now been scrolled out of view. They are all still there, but no longer visible:

[image: sidebar is still there]

The work-around is to search for 'hot network questions', and the browser 'scrolls' the div back into the correct position.

I'm not too much of a CSS wiz, I am not certain how to solve this for this specific page. There are not many linked questions with such huge un-wrappable titles, but perhaps it can be forced to wrap anyway. A `word-wrap: break-word;` on that element certainly works, but there might be undesirable side-effects that I am not aware of.

Comment: The workaround works perfectly.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Added `word-wrap: break-word;` to the sidebar module CSS declaration, which fixes the issue with reallyreallyreallylongwordsbreakingstufflikethis.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.4.10.1540, meta rev 2014.4.10.2154).